# Translating Zend form labels

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, translation

I can't get working form label translations in Zend. I'm still able to translate string in views.

In module.config.php file I have following:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
),
```

In Module.php file I ask users lang from database and set that to language var:

```
$langTableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('users', $dbAdapter);
$this->select = new Select();
$this->select->from('users')
             ->where(array('id' => $userdata['user_id']));
$resultSet = $langTableGateway->selectWith($this->select);
$row = $resultSet->current();        
$user_lang = $row->language;
$e->getViewModel()->setVariable('user_lang', $user_lang);
```

In controllers I have following:

```
    public function indexAction() {

            $loc = $this->getServiceLocator();
            $translator = $loc->get('translator');
            $loc->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('translate')
                                          ->setTranslator($translator);
...
```

Strings in views are translated successfully with `$this->translate('data');`

How I need to change my form files so labels would also be translated? Now I have:

```
class ItemsForm extends Form {

    public $itemsTable;
    public $list;

    public function __construct($name = null) {

        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('items');


        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post')
                ->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'target',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
            ),
        ));


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'title',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'id' => 'title',
                'class' => 'span12',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => _('Item title'),
            ),
        ));
```

What's weird is that if I manually change "module.config.php" file locale to 'fi_FI' form translations work. So I think the problem is that setting user language in "Module.php" or in controller file won't affect to forms.